# Change Maximum/Minimum Scale of secondary axis of Combination Chart

Tags: vba

I have produced a combination scatter (primary) and clustered column (secondary) chart. Whilst the Y values of the datasets I'm showing are different, they all share the same X range.  Thus, I wish to align the minimum and maximum values for the primary and secondary X axes.  This is easy enough for the primary data, but I've having difficulty with those on the secondary axis.

I have tried `.Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary)` but I get an error message stating "Method 'MaximumScale' of object 'Axis' failed."

Any ideas on how I can change the minimum and maximum values of the secondary axis?

Comment: have you tried using the  Macro Recorder and doing it manually to see what VBA code gets generated? that will give you some clues on how to do it in your own code.

Comment: It’s a good idea Joe, but what I’ve come to realise is that the chart setup I have doesn’t seem to have a secondary x axis as such. Whilst the secondary y axis works as per normal, the x axis max and min are seemingly defined by the range of cells, rather than axis parameters. As such, my solution - which seems to work just fine even if it’s not my preferred way of dealing with it - was to write a script that finds the max and min of the primary x axis and then use those values to create a new range for the series collections displayed on the secondary axis.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to specify a range for the secondary x axis series collection that is based upon the min and max values of the primary x axis.